# Angular array not splicing correctly (pure JS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have JSON data that I'm converting to an array for an ng-repeat. Before I iterate through the array, I am comparing the event dates to today's date and splicing the ones that have already passed. However, for some reason, the only thing in the splice getting respected is the deleteCount.

```
    angular.forEach($scope.training, function(event, date) {
        var d = event.endDate;
        var evDate = d.toString();
        console.log(evDate);
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if(dd<10) {
            dd='0'+dd;
        } 
        if(mm<10) {
            mm='0'+mm;
        } 
        today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
        console.log(today);
        var d1 = Date.parse(evDate);
        var d2 = Date.parse(today);
        console.log(d1+','+d2);
        if (d1 <= d2) {
            $scope.training.splice(event,1);
        } else { return false; }
        });
```

and a sample of the JSON:

```
    {"name": "Name","date": "Jan 18","location": "Houston, TX","endDate": "01/19/2016"}
```

Comment: first argument in splice is a number. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am assuming that `$scope.training` is an array, not an object.

The iterator callback for `angular.forEach` has the following signature: `iterator(value, key, obj)`. When applied to an array, `key` holds the index of the item in the array: [angular.forEach documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach).

That means that you can update your code to make the second argument `index` instead of date, and in the splice statement, splice by index.

```
angular.forEach($scope.training, function(event, index) {
    var d = event.endDate;
    var evDate = d.toString();
    console.log(evDate);
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd;
    } 
    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm;
    } 
    today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
    console.log(today);
    var d1 = Date.parse(evDate);
    var d2 = Date.parse(today);
    console.log(d1+','+d2);
    if (d1 <= d2) {
        $scope.training.splice(index,1);
    } else { return false; }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I actually tried a similar approach since angular allows you to access the objects index through the objects array (eg. event.$index) but neither that nor this approach makes any change to the output. BTW, you are correct: I was just showing one object of the array since they are all identical except for the endDate attribute.